# How start Emacs in a console window?

Tags: emacs, console, emacs23

i would like to know how can i launch emacs inside the console window, not in a separated GUI.
Im using emacs 23.2 in Windows.

Comment: Does `emacs -nw` work on Windows?  That is the command to start Emacs in a shell on Unix.

Comment: Try to install cygwin with Emacs

Comment: @Cheeso @jeremiahWillcock if you make an answer i could marks as that, :) that command works.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As I said in my comment,
`emacs -nw` works on Windows.

Comment: this is my favorite : `emacs -nw`
I create a shell replacement, that basically start an `emacs -nw` as the default shell (first run application after user login). 
It run in Console DOS Prompt!
love it

Comment: this answer solved my two month search for running emacs in terminal, thank you. @swdev would you mind giving me hints how I can create a shell replacement then?

Comment: woa. it's been .. what? 12 years? It was using Windows .. XP I think. So, at that time we can easily replace shell=explorer.exe to shell=ourownshell.exe (I forgot where this line was configured). But have a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-shelllauncher And also, I think you can use https://www.autohotkey.com/ to simply run emacs -nw as default shell. Let me know